# Make EditText scroll-able horizontally after a fixed length of Characters in android

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have problem regarding Edit-text in android . I am setting a background of Edit-text and its width is "wrap_content" as below in my code.But when user enter a large text in it the size of the background is exceeded to its actual size

```
    <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edtEmail"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:background="@drawable/text_field"
            android:hint="@string/email_address"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
            android:paddingEnd="20dp"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"

            android:scrollHorizontally="true"
            android:singleLine="true" />
```

So my I want it to be scroll able  horizontally after 30 character .So that I don't exceed its actual size of background .Any help will be appreciable .
Thanks in advance

Comment: i used this already check it in my code

Comment: Now fix width of Edit text to some dps.you will get what you want.

Comment: But i can't fix the width of Edittext as per my mock-ups of my app It should be in center horizontal . Is there is way to define max characters after which it became scroll-able

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try setting this property

```
android:maxEms="4"
```

example: this is my edittext

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/edittext_email_address"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_gray_edittext"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:hint="@string/hint_email_address"
    android:imeOptions="actionNext"
    android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:text="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890qwerty1235"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:maxEms="4"
    android:textColorHint="@color/white70"
    android:textSize="20sp" />
```

hope this works

Answer (score 1):

Set this property to your Edittext and it'll scroll after the number of characters exceed the width.

```
android:singleLine="true"
```